# Pandas DateTimeIndex indexing random multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I am trying to extract random multiple whole day data from pandas DateTimeIndex series, But it returns only the first hour data when the multiple days are passed as a list.

```
dt = pd.date_range('11-1-2022','11-4-2022',freq='6H').to_series()
```

When I want to extract single day it works fine

```
In [204]: dt['11-3-2022']
Out[204]:
2022-11-03 00:00:00   2022-11-03 00:00:00
2022-11-03 06:00:00   2022-11-03 06:00:00
2022-11-03 12:00:00   2022-11-03 12:00:00
2022-11-03 18:00:00   2022-11-03 18:00:00
Freq: 6H, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But when I want to extract multiple random days it only gives the first hour.

```
In [205]: dt[['11-1-2022','11-3-2022']]
Out[205]:
2022-11-01   2022-11-01
2022-11-03   2022-11-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How do I get all hours in the series for a given list of days.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can filter your time series:
Assuming you want all times between '11-1-2022' and '11-3-2022' inclusive:

```
da = dt.where(dt >= pd.to_datetime('11-1-2022')).where(dt <= pd.to_datetime('11-3-2022'))
da.dropna()
```

Yields:

```
2022-11-01 00:00:00    2022-11-01 00:00:00
2022-11-01 06:00:00    2022-11-01 06:00:00
2022-11-01 12:00:00    2022-11-01 12:00:00
2022-11-01 18:00:00    2022-11-01 18:00:00
2022-11-02 00:00:00    2022-11-02 00:00:00
2022-11-02 06:00:00    2022-11-02 06:00:00
2022-11-02 12:00:00    2022-11-02 12:00:00
2022-11-02 18:00:00    2022-11-02 18:00:00
2022-11-03 00:00:00    2022-11-03 00:00:00
2022-11-03 06:00:00    2022-11-03 06:00:00
2022-11-03 12:00:00    2022-11-03 12:00:00
2022-11-03 18:00:00    2022-11-03 18:00:00
```

If you only want data for specific date then you can do:
def selectDates(pdS: pd.Series, itms:list[str]) ->

```
pd.Series:
    rslt = pdS[itms[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(itms)):
        rslt = pd.concat([rslt, pdS[itms[i]]])
    return rslt
```

Then running `selectDates(dt, ['11-1-2022','11-3-2022'])` will yield:

```
2022-11-01 00:00:00   2022-11-01 00:00:00
2022-11-01 06:00:00   2022-11-01 06:00:00
2022-11-01 12:00:00   2022-11-01 12:00:00
2022-11-01 18:00:00   2022-11-01 18:00:00
2022-11-03 00:00:00   2022-11-03 00:00:00
2022-11-03 06:00:00   2022-11-03 06:00:00
2022-11-03 12:00:00   2022-11-03 12:00:00
2022-11-03 18:00:00   2022-11-03 18:00:00
```

Comment: Want for specific days in the list only, not "between" the dates. to list all values between the dates I would actually use dt['11-1-2022':'11-3-2022']

Comment: See edits for how that can be done.

Comment: was looking for a more pythonic or efficient way to do this, If I had to loop through I could just do:  pd.concat([dt[c] for c in ['11-1-2022','11-3-2022']])

Comment: So what makes you think list comprehension is not pythonic?